# _getch() doesn't work on windows server 2012

Tags: c++, c, getch, windows-server-2012

I need a DLL for users can type password and not echo on the screen.
So I use `_getch()` for getting chars with no echo like this,

```
        //get character with no echo
        ch = _getch();
```

and compile the code use microsoft vs2005.
It works on windows server 2003/2008, but on the new  windows server 2012, it echos the characters to the screen.
My problem is why `_getch()` echo characters only on    windows server 2012? and how to fix it?

Comment: at last I found `_getch()` works well, the problem is that I use `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` to check if any stream in `stdin`. I replace them with  `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END)`, its works well in 2012 for now.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `_isatty` to check if the stream is `stdin`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I changed to use `_isatty ` like this `int re = _isatty(_fileno(stdin));`  its works. Is `_isatty` better than `fseek`and why?(I only use it on windows os) thanks a lot.

Comment: Yean, `_isatty` is the 'correct' way to do it. I'm not sure what you mean by "why"... I don't think I've ever read anywhere that `fseek` should be used to determine the input type at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use cin.get() in place of getch() .

Comment: The question is tagged both c and c++; `cin.get()` isn't available in C.

Comment: Yes, but (a) if the OP tagged the question as both c and c++, he's probably looking for a solution that will work in both languages, and (b) `cin.get()` doesn't turn off echoing.